# Return key, value object with dynamic key name

Tags: javascript, peg, pegjs

In PEG.js I have the following rule

```
label  = l:[a-zA-Z\$\#\% ]*  { return word(l); } 
block  = "[" l:label "]" { return l; }
option = "\n"* key:block value:label "\n"? {return {key : value}; }
```

If it parses `[hello] world` it results in:

`{"key": "world"}`.

I would like it to return

`{"hello": "world"}`.

Is this possible? How can I make sure the object key accepts a dynamic value.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500573/dynamic-keys-for-object-literals-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```js
… { return {key : value}; }
```

to

```js
… { var o={}; o[key]=value; return o; }
```

Comment: Yes, using square-bracket notation is the only way to set a dynamic property name.